# Как сравнить значения PHP (RedBeanPHP)?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, redbeanphp

Прошу отнеситесь с понимаем! Я не могу понять, как мне вывести нужные данные из таблицы с помощь RedBeanPHP. Что мне нужно указать в поле которое выделено? Если вдруг будет еще какая то ошибка пожалуйста скажите. Идея такая, что когда пользователь нажимает на кнопку, ему говорится, админ он или нет. Админ имеет в таблице users, в столбце rank цифру 2, у обычного пользователя там значение NULL.
Проверку я сделал по типу вывода ошибки

```
if ( isset($_POST['do_check'])) {
$id = $_SESSION['logged_user']->id;
$rank = $_SESSION['logged_user']->rank;
$user = R::load('users', $rank);
$errors = array();
if ( $user = R::load('users', $rank) > 2) {
    $errors[] = 'Yes';
} else {
    $errors[] =
    'No>';
}
```

}

[image: Code]

Comment: Код сюда надо вставлять __текстом__

Comment: Поправил я это дело

Comment: Ничего сложного. Нужно всего лишь заглянуть в документацию https://redbeanphp.com/index.php?p=/finding. Или вы принципиально не читаете документацию ?!

Comment: Но а как реализовать это, что бы поиск работал, так как с функцией find он все равно не работает

Comment: Вот ответ, все работает
­`if ( isset($_POST['do_check'])) {
    $id = $_SESSION['logged_user']->id;
    $rank = $_SESSION['logged_user']->rank;
    $user = R::load('users', $rank);
    $errors = array();
    $user  = R::find( 'users', ' rank ');
    if ( $rank > 2) {
        $errors[] = 'Yes';
    } else {
        $errors[] ='No';
    }`